# What is the difference between full random and half random

Tags: php, random

Anyone knows the difference between full random and half random function? How can I use them in PHP? Any examples?

Thanks!

Comment: Where did you get these terms from?

Comment: Someone has told me half random is better to generate random images.

Comment: I've never heard of a "half random" function before. Please clarify what you're talking about first.

Answer (score 0):

You likely mean pseudo-random versus truly random. Truly random numbers are generally created from environmental noise or other sources using "TRNGs" (literally truly-random number generators), and are difficult to implement programmatically. Pseudo-random numbers are easier to generate and PHP provides multiple functions for you to obtain them, including mt_rand(). Mt_rand uses the Mersenne twister pseudorandom algorithm which is high in quality compared to the other options.

If you're generating random images in PHP, you need more than random numbers. as you'll need to create a random color value for each pixel of the image. You probably want to do something like this ( which generates a matrix containing color assignments for each pixel in a 50*50 image. You'll need to use GD or ImageMagick to convert it to an actual image )

```php
 <?php
 $pixels = array();
 for($i = 0; $i < 50; ++$i)
 {
     $pixels[$i] = array();
     for($j=0; $j < 50; ++$j)
     {
         $pixel[$i][$j] = hexdec( sprintf("%02X%02X%02X", mt_rand(0, 255), mt_rand(0, 255), mt_rand(0, 255) ) );
     }
 }
```